# prove that ∀ A,B ∈ SL2(Z), (A*B)(z) = A(B(z))

Tags: matrices, analysis

So we got this assignment from math analysis class and I'm really confused because so far we have only covered the bare minimum about matrix (we only covered multiplication and that's it) so I don't have a clue how to approach this.

The professor said to think of A*B as matrix multiplication, and of A(B(z)) as function composition. I don't understand how to, like, see matrix as a function? For example, if A is matrix, what is A(x) supposed to look like?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation

Comment: $(z,w) \mapsto (az+bw,cz+dw)$ is a linear transformation $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$, therefore it is compatible with the multiplication of matrices. The projectivisation is to compose it with $(z,w) \mapsto (\frac{z}{w},1)$.